# change name of facebook open graph action

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to create a new open graph action for my website.
I named the action comment, however was asked to rename it.

Now, its been around 24 hours since I renamed the action, but even now

1. I am able to publish actions with old action name.
2. not able to publish actions with new action name.

I am scared that this situation will revert at any time and my code will break.

Does changing of actions usually take this much time to reflect?
or is there something I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see when you visit the Review Status page? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/#resubmit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What error do you receive from Facebook when you attempt to push an open graph action using the new action name?
2. Is the object name the same from old to new?

Best course of action when encountering this issue is to create a *new* Open Graph story with a new action/object pair, so that both actions are available. Once the new action is working, you can delete the old action.

I have not heard of a situation where a new action takes time to propagate and become available, so this is peculiar...

Comment: Thanks, ended up creating a new Open Graph story.